# ActionScript 3. Error #1009

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, runtime-error

I put `input` text on frame 1 and i put `dynamic` text on frame 3. Users type something in `input` field and click the button. Text should appear. But it doesn't work, it gives me error message:

> Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object
>   reference.

Code:

```
stop();
function handleClick(pEvent:MouseEvent):void {
    var myFirstVar = textField.text;
    Result.text = "Dear " + myFirstVar;
    }
myButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, handleClick);
```

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs because Result is `null` and doesn't exist in frame 1, when your `function` calls it. If you `trace` Result in frame 1, the output will be `null`:

```
trace(Result); // null
```

So none `property` or `method` (like text) can be applied to Result:

```
Result.text = "Dear " + myFirstVar;
```

It would be the same as:

```
nothing.property = something;
```

which is impossible.

To fix it, you can put your `text field` in frame 1. If you try to create your `text input` dynamically in frame 1 and to `addChild` it frame 3, the same error will occur.

**Note:**

Don't name your text field `textField`, which is a `property`. I've named it clearly: *"myName"*

**Your code:**

```
stop();

function handleClick(pEvent:MouseEvent):void {
    // gotoAndStop(3);
    var myFirstVar:String = myName.text; 
    Result.text = "Dear " + myFirstVar;
}

myButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, handleClick);
```